# Which is good Model or Controller

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I want to build a complex project (There will be a lot of data) in Laravel. But I want to write my codes(SQL queries) in Model. I don't want to write these queries in the Controller and I use "Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB" in Model, not in Controller. So I want that my queries will be in Model and other codes in Controller. Is this method good in Laravel? I ask these because I saw that in Other sources that Query Builder uses in Controller. Uses Model but just table name or other functions so other sources write queries in Controller. Am I able to write my quires in Model with Query Builder? Like below.

> Controller  .

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\model_test1;

class model_test extends Controller
{
    function index(){
        $test = new model_test1;
        return $test->fetch();
    }
}
```

> Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class model_test1 extends Model
{
    protected $table="users";
    public function fetch(){

        return  DB::table("users")->get()->where('id',2);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest checking out the [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) docs first. This will explain the basics of Laravel MVC.

Comment: I don't want to use Eloquent. I prefer Query Builder in Model. Is This good method, Use builder in Model?

Comment: I'd personally recommend against putting Query Builder inside Models. But if you really don't want to use Eloquent I'd recommend implementing a Repository pattern as @dev_mustafa suggested.

Comment: Could I ask why you don't suggest put Query Builder inside Models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create repository for each model. One single repository should reflect a model.

The controller should call the repository function to access the data. Below is an example of repository.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Advertisement;
use App\JobAdvertisement;

class UserAdvertisementRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $employeeType
     * @param $userId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdvertisementBasedOnEmployeeType($employeeType, $userId)
    {
        return JobAdvertisement::where('employee_type', $employeeType)
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->paginate(2);
    }

?>
```

You can have a service class too for the business logic.

Comment: Can I use the Model to write DB methods with Query Builder? Because Model is so comfortable place for me.

Comment: Yes, you can but it is not preferred and not best practice in coding standards. Because you model variable can be accessed everywhere and SQL INJECTION attacks can be easily performed.

Comment: But how? How can be accessible Model Class for the public?

Comment: using the model object let suppose you have USER model and 

`$user` is the object for that USER model

`$user->youFunction;`

Comment: We can call a function from Model. Is this not normal? How will be SQL Injection?

Comment: That is normal but those functions should not contain DB call otherwise your project will have security issue

Comment: If you have found my answer useful marked it as useful and accept the answer

Comment: If there is DB call in Model. How does a hacker attack my site? Model functions can't accessible from out.

Comment: using the model object let suppose you have USER model and $user is the object for that USER model `$user->youFunction;`

Comment: Yes, I understood but if a hacker wants this, hacker have to enter my system, my laravels  folders.